# How can I call an Angular function from within the same service if it's within a forEach?

Tags: angularjs, foreach

I have a controller called `PortfolioService`. I created it using the `.service` function (as opposed to `.factory`), and it contains a method `this.findPos`. An internal helper method within the same service needs to call `this.findPos` within a `forEach`:

```
var _getPositions = function() {
  var filtered = _filterBeforeDate();
  filtered.forEach(function(trade){
    var position = this.findPos(trade.symbol);
    [etc...]
  });
};
```

This does not work. `this` within a `forEach` does not reference `PortfolioService` like I want it to, and even if I try to `console.log(this)` outside of the `forEach` block, it only returns the `window`. If I try to call `PortfolioService.findPos()` instead, it logs an error that `PortfolioService is not defined`. If I try to inject `PortfolioService` into itself (not the best idea, I'm sure), it gives an `$injector.cdep` error.

I can't change `this.findPos` to an internal helper method (using `var` instead of `this`) because I need to access `PortfolioService.findPos()` in a controller. What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, but I'd be glad to hear alternatives that may be superior:

I created an internal helper method `var _findPos` which is called within `this.findPos` and also in var `_getPositions`. I'm not certain if this is the most elegant solution, but it works!